# What tool to use to compare and reduce copied over css style sheets?

Tags: css, compare, diff

I have 2 CSS files. The 1st one is a "default" css files (used in all websites that are started from the same templates). The 2nd one is the *real* one for our application. Both file are included in the main master page.

I noticed *someone* copied over or redefined some similar style.

For example, we have `.aligndroite {text-align: right;}` in both file (although, **the formatting is not the same** (1st one is a 1-line declaration, 2nd one is on 3 lines)).

Although, it's *not that bad*, I'd like to remove styles that are declared twice.

I'd like a tool to compare both file and tells me which declaration are present in both files. Does that exist?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225672/what-tool-to-use-to-compare-and-reduce-css-style-sheets) points to [this tool](http://www.alanhart.co.uk/tools/compare-css.php) which does... exactly the opposite of what I need.

Comment: If you need to find duplicates of specific lines of code in your CSS you may always use a text editor such as Sublime Text 2, that highlights multiple instances of the same highlighted text. I don't know some much about comparing multiple CSS Style Sheets. Sublime Text 2: http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Comment: The lines are not duplicate and not in the same order. I clarified it a bit. It's why a tool like winMerge or diffchecker.com won't work. (I suppose Sublime is similar)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Apologies, I wish I could of been more help.

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers have this built in as the "element inspector" - you will be able to see all CSS declarations for an element and which properties are being overwritten.

The rest is really a manual clean-up process. No quick-and-dirty automatic tool for this.

You may want to start a third "merged" stylesheet that you can copy/paste the inspector's CSS into. Ideally you should be able to swap between the current and new stylesheet and both will look the same.

Comment: The files are quite heavy and the gain of this work is too little. Doing it by hand is a no-no. The 'element inspector' is also a no-no, since it work only on the element I select (for example, if `.aligndroite` is used nowhere, I'll never remove it).

Comment: I've managed to merge two 5000-line stylesheets in a few days. Yes, it's a lot of work, but that's why we are called PROFESSIONALS. CSS is much more complex that simply comparing files because CSS is RULE-BASED.